# What difference between serverless computing and a virtual machine scale set

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, cloud-computing

What difference between serverless computing and a virtual machine scale set, if the VM is on autoscale? Is there a difference?

I'm very new to this but I can't see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VM, and VM Scale set are Infrastructure as a Service, you get a virtual machine which you can do whatever you want with, but you are responsible for managing the OS, patching, updates, backups etc. You are also paying for a whole VM when you have it running.

Serverless takes away the VM, all you are concerned about is loading the code you want to run. Underneath it all is VM's, but your not managing this, you know nothing about the underlying VM and do not have to deal with updates etc. You are also only paying for the resource you use (memory and CPU usually) for the time you use it, rather than the whole VM.